# How to modify a List via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I have managed to access a class variable via reflection, and have it stored in a Field variable. I also have the class that field belongs too. How do i transform the Field object in to a List as I want to add to this List using reflection.

The List variable i am accessing via reflection ( and am storing in a Field object) I want to be able to add to it.

Thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class Test 
    {
        private ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        //some methods...
    }

    Field field = myObject.getClass().getField("aList");;
    field.setAccessible(true);
    //some how add an integer to that list
```

Comment: It would help if you showed us something more concrete, e.g. are you talking about setting `bar` in `public class Foo{ private List<?> bar; }` to an instance of a `List`? Or are you talking about changing the type of `bar` in `public class Foo{ private Baz bar; }`?

Comment: could you post some code please?

Comment: List of what exactly ? Can you please provide an example of what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untested:

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = (ArrayList<Integer>) field.get(myObject);
myList.add(5);
```

I am assuming that the above is what you are trying to do?  It is a little bit unclear from your code example.

Also, since the field is private you will need to use getDeclaredField() instead of getField() (as you use in your example).